# ACF Group field not displaying on the front end

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a group field in ACF to display on posts, pages and custom post type. Please see below screenshots.

[image]
[image]

And here's the code I'm trying for front-end.

```
 <?php $footerCTA = get_field('footer_cta');
 echo $footerCTA['title']; ?>
```

The code above doesn't output anything on the front-end. Am I missing here something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
if( have_rows('footer_cta') ):

while( have_rows('footer_cta') ) : the_row(); 

    ?>
    <p><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></p>
    <?php

endwhile;

endif;
```

?>

Comment: did you add them in your WordPress Post/Page loop?
for display custom fields in the page, you should add the_field() function inside the wp loop so for displaying subfield you should do the same. (add this loop in your main wordpress post/page loop).

Comment: what about the location/rules did you set the correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using.

```
 echo the_field('footer_cta');
```

Other Way.

You can do this by adding a second parameter to the `get_field` or `the_field` functions. This second parameter will contain the correct ID which can be found using  `get_option('page_for_posts')` like so

```
<h1><?php the_field('footer_cta', get_option('page_for_posts')); ?></h1>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>



        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```